# JUnit test to match Sting/Words

Tags: java, regex, string, junit

i will write a Junit Test in java, how to check if regex match with the String.

For Example:
String: BLEXABC-A00
String: ALEXABC-D00
String: CLEXABC-C00
String: DLEXABC-B00

This String must be matched for example with the regex [a-zA-Z]lex(abc-[a-zA-Z][0-9])\w?

Thanks

Comment: You do know that javascript and java aren't the same thing right? Nevermind, i've already fixed the tags for you...

Comment: Plus: what did you do to solve your problem? This is actually quite basic and a lot of resources on the web can help you on such thing...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
package ...;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test

public class ... {

    @Test
    public void regexMatches() {
        Assert.assertTrue("BLEXABC-A00".matches("(?i)[a-zA-Z]lex(abc-[a-zA-Z][0-9])\\w"));
        Assert.assertFalse("Brexit".matches("(?i)[a-zA-Z]lex(abc-[a-zA-Z][0-9])\\w"));
    }
}
```

Where regex `(?i)` sets case-insensitive mode. And regex backslashes like in `\w` must be escaped themselves as `\\w`.